# Do I need to pass through emmigration?

Tags: airports, madrid

Next year, I'm going to do OPO - MAD - MIA in Air Europa. 
I've heard that I need to pass through emmigration in Madrid, but I've also heard that I don't need it. 
Is anyone here that knows how emmigration works and if I need it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exiting the Schengen zone in Madrid so you will pass through exit control in Madrid before you board your plane to Miami.

It is not optional.